# Trying to update rows in a loop

Tags: sql-server

There are 3.8 million rows in this table and I am unable to run my update statement. I believe I need to loop through a small section of rows at a time to complete this but I am not familiar with how to loop through the data set in this way.

```
UPDATE dbo.table
SET collectedtime = DateUpdated
WHERE collectedtime IS NULL;
```

Updated this into a cursor, it will run but I have to execute in batches of 500k:

```
DECLARE @Datatoupdate BIGINT
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    Id BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO @Data
(
    Id
)
(SELECT TOP 500000 Raw_ID FROM dbo.table NOLOCK
WHERE collectedtime IS NULL )  -- Id - bigint

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id FROM @Data;

OPEN @Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Datatoupdate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN

        UPDATE dbo.table
        SET CollectedTime = DateUpdated
        WHERE Raw_Id = @Datatoupdate;
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Datatoupdate;
END

Rollback
```

Comment: Please specify your database engine

Comment: Can you disable transaction logging for that operation ?

Comment: What issue you are facing if you execute the script?

Comment: Using Sql Server 2017, I can not disable the transaction log and the error is that the transaction log is full. I can run it in smaller batches, but I would like to tackle it in one statement.

Comment: How to handle this depends on your backup strategy. Nonetheless, there are better ways to handle this entire process. See below.

Comment: @LaughingVergil this is on a production floor, new tool generating data and I don't have access to set up a backup job. I replicate all the data to another environment as it comes in. Cleaning up the transaction log would resolve the issue, but that isn't an option available, so I'm trying to script around the constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately, without cleaning the transaction log (assuming full logging), I don't think that you can necessarily do this. Log file filling is an issue outside of control, other than by backing up the log or setting the server into SIMPLE recovery mode while this is happening.

Comment: Also, just checking, but is there an index on the `collectedtime` field? Assuming that `Raw_Id` is the primary key of the table, an index on `collectedTime` would help the query immensely, since without it a table scan would be needed to find the rows with NULL values.

Comment: When the vendor set up this PC, they didn't have a collectedtime field so I had to add it in, there was already data in the table so the default of getdate() was added to the new collectedtime column for future data but the current data was null. CollectedTime is one of the indexes on the replication side and is also the field that the window's service uses to know which data to pull for replication so I had to have a value in the local to get the data brought over. DateUpdated was the only date field so I just set CollectedTime equal to the initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started down the right path with your batching statements into smaller groups, but you then diverted to handling the data one by one, instead of running a larger batch at a time.  Here is one way I would handle this case:

```
DECLARE @RowCount bigint    -- Control variable to determine when you are done
SET @RowCount = 50000
WHILE @RowCount = 50000 -- If you update less than 50k rows, there are no more rows to update.
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.table
    SET CollectedTime = DateUpdated
    WHERE Raw_Id IN (
        SELECT TOP 50000 Raw_ID 
        FROM dbo.table NOLOCK
        WHERE collectedtime IS NULL 
        )
    SET @RowCount = @@RowCount  -- Get the number of rows updated
/*
To absolutely make the statements work without overfilling the log file, you can perform a 
LOG BACKUP every so often. This will free up space in your log file to complete the remaining
updates. You can either do this with very frequent scheduled log backups, or by manually 
issuing a log backup command every so often in this loop. For example, lets say you were 
tracking the number of updates by incrementing a variable named "@ct", declared to be zero.
If you wanted to perform a log backup after every 500k rows (10 updates), Your code would
look something like this:

    SET @Ct = @Ct + 1  -- Could be Set @Ct += 1 depending on your version of SQL Server
    IF @Ct = 10
    BEGIN
        SET @Ct = 0
        BACKUP LOG <... your backup log command here>
    END
*/
END

Rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic way is doing this:

```
declare @still_there_are_rows int = 1
while @still_there_are_rows > 0
begin
    -- update 1000 rows at a time
    update top (1000) table1 
    set field1 = 1
    where field1 <> 1

    set @still_there_are_rows = (select @@ROWCOUNT)
end
```

When there is no more row to update, @@ROWCOUNT will return ZERO and your loop will end.